# orientdb: passing an Array to a query using 'IN' on an OType.LINKLIST field

Tags: java, sql, orientdb, nosql

I'm trying to pass an array of `Category` POJOs to the query using `IN` in the SQL:

```
public ShareObject[] search(String name, Category[] categories) {
...
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name LIKE ? AND categories IN ?");
List<ODocument> result = db.command(query).execute(name, categories);
```

This will return an empty list. If I change the SQL to the following I get a result:
`"SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name LIKE ? AND categories IN [#10:0,#10:1]"`

I also tried this, without sucess:

```
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name LIKE ? AND categories IN ?");
List<ODocument> result = db.command(query).execute(name, new String[] { "#10:0", "#10:1" });
```

- How do I have to pass the array to the query, IDs or objects?
- Do I have to change the SQL statement?
- Is this even possible?

Comment: What kind of field is 'categories', is it a linklist?

Comment: Yes ShareObject.categories is of the type OType.LINKLIST

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name like ? AND categories IN (?)");
List<ODocument> result = db.command(query).execute(name,"[#10:0,#10:1]");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes this does work, I would prefere to pass an array of objects or ids though.

Comment: With a list of ids
List<String> categories=new ArrayList<String>();
categories.add("#11:0");
categories.add("#11:1");
     
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name like ? AND categories IN (?)");
List<ODocument> result = db.command(query).execute(name,categories.toString());

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
String category="[";
Category[] categories={new Category("#11:3"),new Category("#11:0")};
for(int i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
    if(i==categories.length-1)
        category+=categories[i].getRid()+"]";
    else
        category+=categories[i].getRid()+",";
}
OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> query = new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT FROM ShareObject WHERE name like ? AND categories IN (?)");
List<ODocument> result = db.command(query).execute(name,category);
```